# Get target IP address of an iscsi device from Windows Server

Tags: windows, powershell, iscsi

We have tape libraries connected via iSCSI to our Windows servers.  I'm curious if there's any way at all to retrieve the IP address of the connected device.

I'm able to retrieve the `TargetNodeAddress` with the **Get-IscsiSession** command.. however, it doesn't return a DNS name or IP address.  Already tried looking for it via the iSCSI gui, but I couldn't find it there either.

BTW:  I found the stackoverflow post below that shows how to do this via linux, not Windows:

StackOverflow: [Get target IP address of an iscsi device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44154274/get-target-ip-address-of-an-iscsi-device)

Comment: Perhaps you want to use [Get-IscsiConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iscsi/get-iscsiconnection?view=win10-ps) and take the IP from the `TargetNodeAddress` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `Get-IscsiSession` simply use `Get-IsciConnection` which contains a `TargetAddress` property.

```
ConnectionIdentifier : ffff8a0133d5b010-0
InitiatorAddress     : 0.0.0.0
InitiatorPortNumber  : 194
TargetAddress        : 10.0.0.254
TargetPortNumber     : 3260
PSComputerName       :
```

I do not have a tape device to test with but assume the same would be true for those as well.